# How will Spark react if an RDD gets bigger?

Tags: apache-spark

We have code running in Apache Spark. After a detailed examination of the code, I've determined that one of our mappers is modifying an object that is in an RDD, rather than making a copy of the object for the output. That is, we have an RDD of dicts, and the map function is adding things to the dictionary, rather than returning new dictionaries.

RDDs are supposed to be immutable. Ours are being mutated.

We are also having memory errors.

Question: Will Spark be confused if the size of an RDD suddenly increases?

Comment: Can you show the code ?

Comment: Adding/Deleting/Modifying elements are very common operations on Spark RDD, which easily changes the size of the RDD, I can't find the reason why Spark should be confused.

Comment: @allthenutsandbolts, the code is exceedingly complex. I can try to come up with a minimal example, but our minimal examples won't make spark crash.

Comment: @JiayiLiao, RDDs are immutable. You can add elements to an RDD with a map. But the map is not supposed to modify the RDD on which it operates. For example, in the foreach() documentation, it says "modifying variables other than Accumulators outside of the foreach() may result in undefined behavior."

Comment: @vy32 You mean that you've alreday developed a mutable RDD class, which can be directly modified without creating a new one?

Comment: @JiayiLiao I thought I did, but apparently I didn't! See below.

Answer (score 2):

While it probably does not crash, it can cause some unspecified behaviour. For example this snippet

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize({
    val m = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Int]
    m.put(1, 2)
    m
} :: Nil)
rdd.cache() // comment out to change behaviour!
rdd.map(m => {
    m.put(2, 3)
    m
}).collect().foreach(println) // "Map(2 -> 3, 1 -> 2)"
rdd.collect().foreach(println) // Either "Map(1 -> 2)" or "Map(2 -> 3, 1 -> 2)" depending if caching is used
```

the behaviour changes depending if the RDD gets cached or not. In the Spark API there is a bunch of functions that are allowed to mutate the data and that is clearly pointed out in the documentation, see this for example https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html#aggregateByKey-U-scala.Function2-scala.Function2-scala.reflect.ClassTag-

Consider having a `RDD[(K, V)]` of map entries instead of maps i.e. RDD[Map[K, V]]. This would enable adding new entries in a standard way using `flatMap` or `mapPartitions`. If needed, the map representation can be eventually generating by grouping etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I developed some code to test out what happens if an object referred to in an RDD is mutated by the mapper, and I am happy to report that it is not possible if you are programming from Python.

Here is my test program:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import time

COUNT = 5
def funnydir(i):
    """Return a directory for i"""
    return {"i":i,
            "gen":0 }

def funnymap(d):
    """Take a directory and perform a funnymap"""
    d['gen'] = d.get('gen',0) + 1
    d['id' ] = id(d)
    return d

if __name__=="__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext

    dfroot = sc.parallelize(range(COUNT)).map(funnydir)
    dfroot.persist()
    df1 = dfroot.map(funnymap)
    df2 = df1.map(funnymap)
    df3 = df2.map(funnymap)
    df4 = df3.map(funnymap)



    print("===========================================")
    print("*** df1:",df1.collect())
    print("*** df2:",df2.collect())
    print("*** df3:",df3.collect())
    print("*** df4:",df4.collect())
    print("===========================================")

    ef1 = dfroot.map(funnymap)
    ef2 = ef1.map(funnymap)
    ef3 = ef2.map(funnymap)
    ef4 = ef3.map(funnymap)
    print("*** ef1:",ef1.collect())
    print("*** ef2:",ef2.collect())
    print("*** ef3:",ef3.collect())
    print("*** ef4:",ef4.collect())
```

If you run this, you'll see that the id for the dictionary `d` is different in each of the dataframes. Apparently Spark is serializing deserializing the objects as they are passed from mapper to mapper. So each gets its own version.

If this were not true, then the first call to `funnymap` to make df1 would also change the generation in the `dfroot` data frame, and as a result ef4 would have different generation numbers that df4.